# API de notícias como serviço

Tags: android, web-service, api, rest, services

Gostaria de exibir notícias aleatórias do Brasil e do mundo no meu app enquanto o usuário está processando uma requisição. Alguém conhece algum serviço/API que possa me prover um Json de faço manuseio?

Comment: Um mecanismo que leia RSS é mais interessante porque é um formato padrão e presente em todos os veículos de notícia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De uma olhada na api do The new York Times segue o link como referencia para poder ajudar.

https://developer.nytimes.com/